# Is it better to store my Strings on Front-End or Back-End

Tags: database, string, frontend, backend, superglobals

This question is a little more generic, a brainstorm one. I'm about to develop a small website, and I still don't know if it’s better for me to store my “Text” (to fill Labels, Messages, etc) data on the Database or just on the frontend.

I know that for a fact, consulting the BackEnd Database is slower than just searching a specific file, but it’s also better to update the list later-on (when the website is developed) by just running a script.

I want to know some opinions, experiences, advantages and disadvantages about both.

Edit: For the technologies, i was thinking in using ExtJS with a Java Backend, I'm not quite sure about the BD yet.

Comment: What does "consulting the BD" mean? Is that a typo for "DB", or perhaps an abbreviation for "Backend Database"?

Comment: @BryanOakley Fixed, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Consider what data you are storing and the purpose of your website.

Advantages of front end storage: quicker

Advantages of database storage: more secure/structured

If your strings are sensitive then I would secure them in your database. Any client information, including "Text" data should be stored on the back end. If the strings are only relevant to you as the site owner then I don't see a problem with storing them on the front end.

Also perhaps specify which technologies you are using to build this site to get more specific responses.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking in using ExtJS with a Java Backend, I'm not quite sure about the BD yet, maybe oracle.